# multiple values for class attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i am trying to use beautifulsoup to get birthdays for persons from wikipedia. for example the birthday for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezra_Taft_Benson is August 4, 1899. to get to the bday, i am using the following code:

```
bday = url.find("span", class_="bday")
```

However it is picking up the instance where `bday` appears in the html code as part of another tag. i.e `<span class="bday dtstart published updated">1985-11-10 </span>`.

is there a way to match the exact class tag with `bday` only?

I hope the question is clear as currently I am getting the `bday` to be 1985-11-10 which is not the correct date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When all other matching methods of BeautifulSoup fail, you can use a function taking a single argument (tag):

```
>>> url.find(lambda tag: tag.name == 'span' and tag.get('class', []) == ['bday'])
<span class="bday">1899-08-04</span>
```

The above searches for a `span` tag whose class attribute is a list of a single element ('bday').

Comment: this was a great simple solution! thanks. what is the lambda tag doing?

Comment: The `lambda` creates an anonymous function with a single argument (tag). You could define a separate, named function and pass its name to `find()` instead, but for short, one-off functions `lambda` is [more preferable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/890188/12320).

Answer (score 1):

I would have gone about it this way:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezra_Taft_Benson'
file_pointer = urllib.urlopen(url)
html_object = BeautifulSoup(file_pointer)

bday = html_object('span',{'class':'bday'})[0].contents[0]
```

This returns `1899-08-04` as the value of `bday`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) with the `beautifulsoup` parser. The following finds `<span>` tags with only the `bday` class (which in the case of this page there is only one):

```
>>> from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
>>> root = fromstring(open('Ezra_Taft_Benson'))
>>> span_bday_nodes = root.findall('.//span[@class="bday"]')
[<Element span at 0x1be9290>]
>>> span_bday_node[0].text
'1899-08-04'
```